# how create array represents A,B,,,Z, when specific character clicked, the words include this character displayed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

Creating array represents A,B,,,Z, or when specific character clicked, the words in characters array displayed in DIV attribute.

for more explanation for example:the first array alphabets ={a,b,c,d,...,z} when user click character "A" all the words from array A={"add","as","and"} that included character "A" display in DIV, for others characters "B" "C" ....."Z" same method will applied. so need your help my friends.

```
$(function(){ $('#make-word').click(function() { var $this = $(this); var letters = $('#my-word').val().split(''); letters = '<div class="character">'+letters.join('</div><div class="character">')+'</div>'; initDragable($('#word-container').html(letters).find('.character')); $('.character').click(function() { $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" ); });
```

Comment: Can you please add sample data and code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: i wanna apply above explained to this code !

Comment: '$(function(){
    $('#make-word').click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var letters = $('#my-word').val().split('');
      letters = '<div class="character">'+letters.join('</div><div class="character">')+'</div>';
   
      initDragable($('#word-container').html(letters).find('.character'));
   
$('.character').click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
  
  
});'

Comment: when character click highlight then show words included this character !